# Visual Studio 2012 - Add multiple items on same writeline

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2012

Okay, so what i"m doing is creating a word file with my application with my labels and `textboxes` to create a receipt. In my word file, I am trying to write what is in a first name `label` beside what is in a last name `label`.

Here is the code I have, but I just seem to be missing something, because the word file keeps putting a huge gap between the first name and last name. I'm sure it's a very simple fix, but Google doesn't seem to be helping with what I am trying to describe.

```
printFile.WriteLine("Name: " & vbTab & FirstNameTextBox.Text + LastNameTextBox.Text)
```

Comment: Did you try Trim()? Also, it could be a word thing altogether. When you open word, is your text left aligned or justified? If it is justified, add a NewLine after your text.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it must be the vbTab keyword.

which is fixed and cannot be changed.
That said you can manage a workaround as follows:

```
Public Const MyTab = "   "
```

and in your code

```
printFile.WriteLine("Name: " & MyTab & FirstNameTextBox.Text + LastNameTextBox.Text)
```